# amp image getting stretched, for responsive layout

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I am trying to contain an image in a wrapper, maintaining its aspect ratio. However the image stretches out.
Below is a sample amp html, where I am facing the issue.

```
<style>
    .image-wrapper {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: teal;
    }
    .image-wrapper img {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 150px;
        max-height: 150px;
    }
</style>
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <amp-img
        src="http://fyogi.com/public/images/products/mobiles/lg-google-nexus-5x-mqqci.c1.w150.jpg"
        layout="responsive" 
        width="150" 
        height="150">
    </amp-img>
</div>
```

After rendering the page, this is the amp version

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <amp-img src="http://fyogi.com/public/images/products/mobiles/lg-google-nexus-5x-mqqci.c1.w150.jpg" layout="responsive" width="130" height="130" class="-amp-element -amp-layout-responsive -amp-layout-size-defined -amp-layout" id="AMP_1"><i-amp-sizer style="display: block; padding-top: 100%;"></i-amp-sizer>
    <img amp-img-id="AMP_1" class="-amp-fill-content -amp-replaced-content" width="130" height="130" src="http://fyogi.com/public/images/products/mobiles/lg-google-nexus-5x-mqqci.c1.w150.jpg"></amp-img>
</div>
```

Below style which is being added by the amp after render, **caused** it to stretch the image, **adding min-width: 100%** to the img element

```
.-amp-fill-content {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Now I can **fix** this with a workaround by adding **min-width: auto**, but it would defeat the purpose of using amp html layout responsive, and the doc, clearly says that for **layout responsive**

> Element sized to the width of its container element and resizes its height **automatically to the aspect ratio given by width and height attributes**.

**Problem Statement**

I have image source with unknown dimensions, but smaller than 150X150px, ideally, either width or height will be 150px. I need this image to be aligned in center/middle(both horizontal and vertical) of a fixed 150X150 division, also if possible I would like to keep all the dimensions in em/rem.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878352/is-it-possible-to-make-images-responsive-in-amp-html-or-i-need-to-declare-the-im/33897457#33897457 which might help.

Comment: seen it already, wont help :(

Answer (score 2):

try by adding amp-img to your CSS code

```
.image-wrapper img, .image-wrapper amp-img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be help full....

object-fit: contain increases or decreases the size of the image to fill the container whilst preserving the image's aspect-ratio.

https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/how_to_support_images_with_unknown_dimensions/

```
 <style>
.fixed-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 }
 amp-img.contain img {
  object-fit: contain;
 }
   </style>

<div class="flex">
 <div class="fixed-container m1">
<amp-img class="contain"
  layout="fill"
  src="https://unsplash.it/400/300"></amp-img>
</div>
<div class="fixed-container m1">
<amp-img class="contain"
  layout="fill"
  src="https://unsplash.it/300/300"></amp-img>
 </div>
 <div class="fixed-container m1">
<amp-img class="contain"
  layout="fill"
  src="https://unsplash.it/200/300"></amp-img>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that might help.

```
.image-wrapper img {
//      object-fit: contain; just this line alone can do below job but it's not working in IE. 
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        right: inherit;
        bottom: initial;
        max-height: 100%;
        min-width: initial;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
```

This code also work fine with responsive AMP carousel.

> Note: Do not try to add `!important` else AMP validation will be
>   failed.