# Responsive <amp-img> with a container height

Tags: amp-html

I'd like to put a small `<amp-img>` inline on a line of text. The use case is inserting a latex formula on a line of text. I know the image's width and height in advance, but I don't know the height of that line of text as the line height responds to changes in browser size (larger text for desktop, smaller text for mobile phones).

`<amp-img layout=responsive>` adjusts the image size proportionally based on the container's width. Is there a similar mechanism that can be used to adjust the image size proportionally based on the container's height?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [documenatation of AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout.html) about responsive layout, the element sized to the width of its container element and resizes its height automatically to the aspect ratio given by width and height attributes. This layout works very well for most of AMP elements, including amp-img, amp-video. Available space depends on the parent element and can also be customized using max-width CSS.

Check also the `@media` that control the page layout looks and behaves, as you would do on any other website. When the browser window changes size or orientation, the media queries are re-evaluated and elements are hidden and shown based on the new results.

```
<amp-img
media="(min-width: 650px)"
src="wide.jpg"
width=466
height=355
layout="responsive" >
</amp-img>
```

For more information using CSS check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149114/amp-image-getting-stretched-for-responsive-layout).

Comment: This helps if I want the `<amp-img>` to resize it's height to the available width. In this case, I would like the element to resize it's width to the available height.