# amp img not loading in css input tabs but loads on browser resize

Tags: amp-html

I have a site page where i want to load the news feed with a image and its text. I am using `amp-img` to load the images. The active tab loads the text and images fine, but when switching between the tabs, the content loads but `amp-img` does not. It loads when i resize the browser.

Please suggest some solution. Thanks!

Comment: Upon checking the link you've provided, there are some errors and warning that makes your page invalid using the [amp validator](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate). Try adding `layout="responsive"` as stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33897457/5995040) which link this http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/bonfire-night-2015-how-keep-6767214.amp page for example. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your page contains some javascript:

```
<script src="js/stickUp.min.js"></script>
  function tabrefresh(){....
```

which is not allowed in AMP, this is causing an error. I also noticed you are using input outside a form which is not allowed as well, you could use href to implement tabs instead.

Check all the errors by adding #development=1 to the URL, like http://templatefort.com/projects/clubcall/25Jan/index.html#development=1

Comment: also, all styles must be inline (except for the fonts - which you have declared correctly). An you can't run jQuery either.